# How to use collect with multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
d = [2,4,6]
d.collect{ |i| i * 2 } #=> [4,8,12]
```

I tried to do the same with multi-dimensional array

```
d = [[1,3],[2,4]]
d.collect { |i,j| i*2, j*2 } #=> getting syntax error
```

Comment: Not sure what behaviour you're looking for, so I'm a bit guessing:
`d = [[1,3],[2,4]]`

`d.collect { |i,j| [i*2, j*2] }`

Comment: I was expecting something like `[[2,6][4,8]]`

Comment: Inside of a block must stand alone as a syntactically valid Ruby code. `i*2, j*2` is not valid Ruby.

Comment: @sawa: Got it. If it were `{|i,j| i,j = i * 2, j * 2}` then it would have worked :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To represent array, you need to surround them with `[` and `]`:

```
d.collect { |i,j| [i*2, j*2] }
#                 ^        ^
# => [[2, 6], [4, 8]]
```